# How do I get the inverse bind pose matrix from the 2018 FBX SDK?

Tags: animation, graphics, maya, fbx

I'm writing a tool to extract the necessary data from an .fbx file to be written onto a custom file and loaded into a game engine. I have meshes, joints, and skeleton animations working and displaying properly, but I can't seem it to get it to work when I incorporate skinning.

I display the skeletal animations by transforming the origin point recursively through the bone tree's keyframe transforms and drawing lines between them:

[Skeleton Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be3oV.gif)

I'm pretty sure I've logically narrowed it down to incorrectly obtaining the inverse bind pose matrix from the file, since the skeletal animation looks accurate.

This is how I obtain the inverse bind pose:

```
            // Find the joint associated with this cluster
      FbxCluster *fbx_cluster = fbx_skin->GetCluster(i_cluster);
      std::string joint_name = fbx_cluster->GetLink()->GetName();
      auto joint = std::find(model.m_skeleton.m_joints.begin(), model.m_skeleton.m_joints.end(), joint_name);

      FbxAMatrix transform_matrix;
      FbxAMatrix transform_link_matrix;
      FbxAMatrix parent_transform_link_matrix;

        // Calculate bind pose matrix, which is the starting transformation matrix
      fbx_cluster->GetTransformMatrix(transform_matrix);
      fbx_cluster->GetTransformLinkMatrix(transform_link_matrix);

      const FbxVector4 lT = fbx_cluster->GetLink()->GetGeometricTranslation(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);
      const FbxVector4 lR = fbx_cluster->GetLink()->GetGeometricRotation(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);
      const FbxVector4 lS = fbx_cluster->GetLink()->GetGeometricScaling(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);

      FbxAMatrix geom(lT, lR, lS);

      joint->m_jointNode = fbx_cluster->GetLink();
      joint->m_inverseBindPose = transform_link_matrix.Inverse() * transform_matrix * geom;
      joint->m_isBindPoseSet = true;
```

According to various articles online, the "transform_matrix" and "geom" are there for compatibility with other software and are usually just the identity matrix, and I have confirmed them to be just that. So I basically call GetTransformLinkMatrix and invert it. Then for the joints that do not have a cluster associated with it, I do this:

```
  // If the joint didn't have a cluster, it wasn't a part of binding, and therefore
  // doesn't have an inverse bind pose. We have to make one here
if (!joint.m_isBindPoseSet) {
  joint.m_isBindPoseSet = true;
  joint.m_globalBindPoseMatrix = joint.m_jointNode->EvaluateLocalTransform().Inverse() * model.m_skeleton.m_joints[joint.m_parentIndex].m_inverseBindPoseMatrix;
}
```

Which is just, getting the local transformation of the joint and multiplying it with the inverse bind pose of its parent. I have tried this with 3 different animated rigs and the skinning for none of them works. This is an example of what it looks like:

[Skinning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hvJ5.gif)

I feel like I've done a lot of research on this, but I don't know what's wrong. I'm using DirectX 11 if that's relevant at all. I'm also using fbx files exported from Maya created by some artist friends. (And one maya file i found off the internet, which I exported myself). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FbxAMatrix inverse_bindpose = joint->EvaluateGlobalTransform().Inverse();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I forgot to mention that I already tried that. This is what I get: https://imgur.com/MsdB7Bf
The first frame ends up being closer to the original bind pose.